# TableAdapter always returns null for scalar function in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2013, tableadapter

I encountered a weird behavior that I could narrow down in a simple sample project.

*I am trying to translate the corresponding visual studio terms from German to English*

The components included:
- Visual Studio 2013 Express
- C#
- MSSQL Server 2008 R2
- .NET Framework 4.5
- using DataSet and a Query

The sample function is very simple:

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fTest]
    (   )
    RETURNS INT
    AS
    BEGIN
        RETURN 42
    END
```

Then I included a DataSet and included a Query through the TableAdapter Configuration Assistant using an "existing stored procedure" leaving it with the default settings. Visual Studio has a "Data Preview" Feature on the context menu. There I will receive the correct result value.

Now adding some simple code:

```
    using functionTest.DataSet1TableAdapters;
    using System;

    namespace functionTest
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                QueriesTableAdapter qta = new QueriesTableAdapter();
                object result = qta.fTest();
                int? resI = (int?)result;
                Console.WriteLine("result: " + resI);
            }
        }
    }
```

Strangely result will always be null.

**EDIT:**

the generated TableAdapter Code:

```
namespace functionTest.DataSet1TableAdapters {


    /// <summary>
    ///Represents the connection and commands used to retrieve and save data.
    ///</summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(true)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectAttribute(true)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerAttribute("Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.Design.TableAdapterDesigner, Microsoft.VSDesigner" +
        ", Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
    public partial class QueriesTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {

        private global::System.Data.IDbCommand[] _commandCollection;

        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        protected global::System.Data.IDbCommand[] CommandCollection {
            get {
                if ((this._commandCollection == null)) {
                    this.InitCommandCollection();
                }
                return this._commandCollection;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        private void InitCommandCollection() {
            this._commandCollection = new global::System.Data.IDbCommand[1];
            this._commandCollection[0] = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[0])).Connection = new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(global::functionTest.Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString);
            ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[0])).CommandText = "dbo.fTest";
            ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[0])).CommandType = global::System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this._commandCollection[0])).Parameters.Add(new global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", global::System.Data.SqlDbType.Int, 4, global::System.Data.ParameterDirection.ReturnValue, 10, 0, null, global::System.Data.DataRowVersion.Current, false, null, "", "", ""));
        }

        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
        public virtual object fTest() {
            global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = ((global::System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand)(this.CommandCollection[0]));
            global::System.Data.ConnectionState previousConnectionState = command.Connection.State;
            if (((command.Connection.State & global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open) 
                        != global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)) {
                command.Connection.Open();
            }
            object returnValue;
            try {
                returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
            finally {
                if ((previousConnectionState == global::System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)) {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
            if (((returnValue == null) 
                        || (returnValue.GetType() == typeof(global::System.DBNull)))) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return ((object)(returnValue));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** 
another Hint: The internal CommandCollection contains the valid result. I veried this in the debugger and also by exposing the CommandCollection and accessing it:

```
IDataParameterCollection test = qta._commandCollection[0].Parameters;
SqlParameter param = (SqlParameter) test[0];
int? res = (int?) param.Value;
```

Comment: Can you share source of QueriesTableAdapter ?

Comment: This will occurs when data type doesn't match between C# and SQL server. However we can provide specific reason after providing the source code of QueriesTableAdapter.

Comment: try this, int? resI = (int?)result.ToString();

Comment: Thank you for editing the title. "int? resI = (int?) result.ToString();" leads to the compiler error "cannot convert from type string to int?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the object returned from the scalar valued function is always null using  command.executescalar().

So the returnvalue cannot be retrieved this way. I think it is a MS problem because this is certainly the obvious way of doing it.

A work around is to edit the generated code above as follows:

replace

```
returnValue = command.ExecuteScalar();
```

with

```
command.ExecuteScalar();
returnValue = command.Parameters["@RETURN_VALUE"].Value;
```

Of course the "@RETURN_VALUE" has to match the name assigned in your tableadapter.

This worked for me... hope it helps.

If you edit the generated code